# Position Dock stretched full width without increasing size proportionally

Tags: dock, ui, defaults

Using

```
defaults write com.apple.dock pinning start;killall Dock
```

I was able to move the position of the dock to the upper left corner below the Apple menu.

What I'd really like to do is force the dock to take up the full space available with empty space like this mock..

↙ Current            Wanted ↘

[image]

Comment: It seems this doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was hoping to find an alternative solution but I was able to achieve what I wanted by

```
defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array-add '{"tile-type"="spacer-tile";}'
```

running that command several times (5 times actually) created 5 spaces in the dock which I just placed to one side to make it long enough to fill up the full height.

Now it looks like this

[image]